# GAE Python NDB Datastore - No need for memcache.set?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, app-engine-ndb

The documentation (https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/) states that

> NDB uses Memcache as a cache service for "hot spots" in the data

I am now using `memcache` only as follows:
`memcache.set(key=(id), value=params, time=0)`

That expires (auto flushes) pretty often and so I would like to use NDB Datastore.
I thought I would have to always put the key-value in both NDB and Memcache, then check both.
Is this being done automatically by NDB?

Ie. 
`ancestor_key = ndb.Key("Book", guestbook_name or "*notitle*")`

`greetings = Greeting.query_book(ancestor_key).fetch(20)`

Would that implicitly set `Memcache` ?

And when I read from NDB, would it implicitly try a `memcache.get(key)` first?

Thanks for your patience.

EDIT - What I tried:

As a test I tried something like this:

```
class Book(ndb.Model):
    content = ndb.StringProperty() 

class update(webapp2.RequestHandler): 
    def post(self): 
        p1='1' 
        p2='2' 
        p3='3' 
        p4='4' 
        p5='5' 
        id='test'
        paramarray = (p1,p2,p3,p4,p5) 

        book = Book(name=id,value=paramarray) 
        # OR likes this -  book = Book(ndb.Key(id),value=paramarray)          
        book.put()
```

Both versions error out. 
Trying to get a key of the var `id` with the values of `paramarray`

**EDIT 2** Daniel, Thank you for everything.

Have follow up formatting questions, will ask a new question.

Comment: The appstats page will show you rpc requests so you can verify your memcache get/set behavior.

Comment: @JoshJ Thanks, that sounds useful and I'll try that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes; see the full documentation on [ndb caching](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/cache). Basically, every write is cached both in a request-local in-context cache, and in the main memcached store; a get by key will look up in both caches first before falling back to the real datastore.

**Edit** I can't understand why you think your example would work. You defined a model with a `content` property, but then try to set `name` and `value` properties on it; naturally that will fail.

You should go through the [ndb documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/), which gives a good introduction to using the model class.

Comment: Thanks Daniel, that saves some checking.

Could you help me with a simple example of how to set a simple key-value into Datastore?
In the documentation I see an `ndb.key` but do not understand where the value is. Is there a simple syntax like the `memcache,set()` one?

I do not want to bother with ancestors or anything, just a simple put of key and value.

Comment: Assuming you have a Book model, you can create a new book without an ancestor with `book = Book(name="The Hobbit", author="JRR Tokien")` and then save it with `book.put()`. The put call returns the key.

Comment: Thank you. Lacking a bit of Pyhon here.
Unlike `memcache.set()`, here I have to first create a new `class`? ie, `class Greeting(ndb.Model):` and then use that in my `MainPage`?

Can't I make it simpler by putting the simple `put` statement directly in `MainPage`? (again, going back to my `memcache.set()` example, which was easier for me.

Comment: You can't save things to the datastore unless they are in a model, no.

Comment: Or rather, you *could*, but only by mucking around with some of the base Entity protocol buffer classes, but you definitely don't want to be doing that.

Comment: As a test I tried something like this:

   class Book(ndb.Model):
           content = ndb.StringProperty()
  class update(webapp2.RequestHandler):
       def post(self):
          p1='1'
          p2='2'
           p3='3'
          p4='4'
          p5='5'
          id='test' 
           paramarray = (p1,p2,p3,p4,p5)
          book = Book(name=id,value=paramarray)
          # book = Book(ndb.Key(id),value=paramarray)
        book.put()

Both versions error out.
Trying to get a key of the var `id` with the values of `paramarray`


Code formatting does not work. Sorry

Comment: I can't really read that, please add it as an edit in your question.